# How can I get the cartesian product of lists that are values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, cartesian-product

I have a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'item1':[1,2,3],'item2':[10,20,30]}
```

I want to create the cartesian product of the two so that I get a tuple of each possible pair.

```
output: [(1,10),(1,20),(1,30),
         (2,10),(2,20),(2,30),
         (3,10),(3,20),(3,30)]
```

It seems like there would be a simple way to do this so that it extends if I have three items.  Kind of like a dynamic number of loops.  Feels like I am missing an obvious way to do this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function will do this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> mydict = {'item1':[1,2,3],'item2':[10,20,30]}
>>> list(itertools.product(*mydict.values()))
[(10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3), (20, 1), (20, 2), (20, 3), (30, 1), (30, 2), (30, 3)]
```

If you need to control the order of the resulting tuples, you can do

```
itertools.product(mydict['item1'], mydict['item2'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also brute force it using two loops

```
mydict = {'item1':[1,2,3],'item2':[10,20,30]}

x = []
for i in mydict['item1']:
    for j in mydict['item2']:
        x.append((i,j))
```

All this code does is go through all of the item in `mydict['item1']`, then through each item in `mydict['item2']`, then appends a pair of each to a new list.

It will give you this result:

```
[(1, 10), (1, 20), (1, 30), (2, 10), (2, 20), (2, 30), (3, 10), (3, 20), (3, 30)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[(i, j) for i in mydict['item1'] for j in mydict['item2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do two for loops.
- the first one would keep track of the index position of the first item list. 
-The second loop would go through each item in the second. 
- After it runs through all the items, the first for loop would increment to the next item in its list and the second loop will run through the second list again, etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30228048/4087357)